# Trying to install Erlang on Ubuntu 12.04, error with make install

Tags: 12.04, make

I am trying to install Erlang R16B on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. I get an error which says:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -d "/usr/local/lib/erlang"
/usr/bin/install: cannot change permissions of `/usr/local/lib/erlang': No such file or directory
make: *** [install.dirs] Error 1
```

I'm following a [tutorial](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/#Installing-on-GNU-Linux) on docs.basho.com to install it and well, they didn't cover what to do and I have a hard time finding answers on Google. I found [another post](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html) on erlang.org about installing it here but it didn't help me and it was just about generally installing it, not about errors like these. Anyhow, I hope somebody has any idea on what I can do to fix this :)

I intend to learn Erlang to basically make a server, to learn how it works. My own little project.

Answer (score 2):

You need permission to modify system folders. Try:

```
sudo make install
```

PS: why don't you install erlang from Ubuntu repositories? Just run `sudo apt-get install erlang`.

Comment: Because it was apparently outdated
I did the sudo ./configure && make && make install

Doesn't sudo go over all the commands?

Comment: No, you should `sudo` only `make install`. But sudoing each command won't hurt.

Comment: You can also try `sudo -s` and then configure and make...

Comment: Okey, I see. It worked great! Now I feel stupid for not realising that though haha. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but to the later question: "PS: why don't you install erlang from Ubuntu repositories? Just run sudo apt-get install erlang."

The version in the repositories is extremely out of date and does not support a huge amount of software that is currently available. I believe it is version 14.4 while the latest stable version is 16.2.

For instance, you need version 16 or above to run elixir.

I hope this helps answer your question.